# XML in Indesign - how to use attributes to assign formating

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, xml

I wanted to use XML to design a big festival programme. Unfortunately the XML consist only of text elements that have certain attributes (like date, time, type, etc) assigned to them.

I can rename the text elements to whatever I want to name them by selecting them and assign them a new mark. But how can I automatically do this for the entire document?

Is there a way to tell Indesign to mark the elements depending on their attributes?

Comment: You can add a XSL Transformation rule to the xml to repurpose it into a form that makes more sense for this purpose. A bit long wided example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMdc2psf01Y

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the tag applied to another one you can simply remove that tag from the tags panel, you will be asked to choose for another tag. That's the quickiest way. Of course you may want to recreate that deleted tag if needed.

If you want to rename the tag based on an attribute of its, you may need either XSLT to change XML on the fly or a script to do it later.

Comment: Hi ozalto, welcome to GD SE, and thanks for your answer. I've edited your post to remove the self-promoting link. Site policy is to keep personal promotion to the large about section on our profile pages, which people will easily find by clicking on your name.

Comment: ok, sorry about that. Will stick to the rules ;)